# How to background avoid background colour from spreading all over the page?

Tags: css, html

This is my HTML code

```css
.paragraph1 {
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-family: Verdana;
  color: #9069CA;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-right: 420px;
  padding-left: 135px;
}
```

```html
<div class='paragraph1'>
  <p>
    This is the paragraph.
  </p>
</div>
```

How do I stop the paragraph background color from spreading all over the page?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
.paragraph1 {
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-family: Verdana;
  color: #9069CA;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-right: 420px;
  padding-left: 135px;
  display: inline-block;
    }
```

or

```
.paragraph1 {
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-family: Verdana;
  color: #9069CA;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-right: 420px;
  padding-left: 135px;
  width:1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
 }
```

Comment: What does this do? How does it answer the question? Don't just throw markup out there. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: It wrap the contents inside your div and then background will not spread over the page.

Comment: How does it do that? You aren't answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

you want the background for just the paragraph then change:

```
<div>
    <p class="paragraph`">This is it</p>
</div>
```

Comment: No actually I have done that but the background colour spreads from the paragraph further to right..

Comment: that's because you have padding. If you still want the padding properties then move them to another class and keep the background-color to the p element

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't spread all over the page - it only covers the `.paragraph` DIV in your code. If that DIV will also contain other elements and you want to restrict the background to `p` elements inside it and you can't change the HTML (as in the answer before me), you can change the CSS:

```css
.paragraph1 {
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-family: Verdana;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-right: 320px;
  padding-left: 135px;
}
.paragraph1 > p {
  background: black;
  color: #9069CA;
}
```

```html
<div class='paragraph1'>
  <p>
    This is the paragraph.
  </p>
</div>
```